# A question about the difference between men and women

Tags: nature-of-god, forgiveness, gender

Because the Bible teaches that God made men directly in His image but women indirectly (1 Timothy 2:13) and that God transcends all moral judgment (Romans 9:20), what does this imply about the ability of men to receive forgiveness, as compared to women?

I weigh answers from the Church Fathers the highest, preferably Latin and Greek fathers during the first millennia.

Comment: You should add a denominational specification. As it stands, the question is very open to opinion-based answers

Comment: "Because the Bible teaches that God made men directly in His image but women indirectly" I don't know any denominations that would teach this!

Comment: The question is still open to opinion-based answers, and, as @curiousdannii points out, most of those opinions are likely to be "your question is wrong." I've voted to close, but I would highly suggest targeting this to a denomination that teaches the premise, or refocus to ask why mainstream Christianity would teach that this premise is not sound doctrine.

Comment: @curiousdannii I would like to know more about the spiritual differences between men and women for a story I'm writing.

Comment: _Adam was first formed, then Eve_ makes no comment on 'direct' or 'indirect' image presentation. The question is based on an opinion without any evidence.

Comment: @NigelJ DJClayworth says that 1 Timothy 2:13 does mention direct and indirect. And I carefully did not base my question on an opinion, because opinion presupposes judgment, which presupposes a form of the verb "to be" and if you read the question carefully you will find that there does not exist any conjugation of the verb "to be".

Comment: @HolyKnowledge No I do not say that. And the verse does not say that. That was a typing mistake.

Comment: The absence of a copular verb does not predispose the absence of an opinion. Opinion can be expressed using any form of grammar. The concept you are attempting to introduce is just not present in the text you quote. Perhaps you should try your question on [Stack Exchange - Biblical Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions) and then  we may analyse it in detail.

Comment: @NigelJ Your request seems fair. Here: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/86162/a-question-on-the-difference-between-men-and-women I am ready.

Comment: On the basis of DJClayworth's biblical answer, I wonder why you say you "weigh answers from the Church Fathers the highest."  Which Church Fathers?  Those from the first and second centuries? Or later? Perhaps you should edit your question to provide more detail, otherwise the question may be (regretably) closed.

Comment: @Lesley I added a temporal boundary on when I want the church fathers to come from. Glad to know that you think this question is valuable. Thank you for the uplifting word (Proverbs 15:4).

Comment: A time-frame of 1,000 years is a millennium, which is a very long period of time indeed!

Comment: @Lesley because thinking and communication happened slower back in those days, and also because gender wasn't a hot topic among the church, I need a longer slice of history to track the conclusions these church fathers made, the direction their thinking was heading, and also to get a deep enough breadth of sampling on a rare subject (gender).

Answer (score 4):

The foundational point of this question is incorrect. Men and women are both created in the image of God, and there is no mention of "directly" or "indirectly". The "order" of creation specified in 1 Tim 2:13 does not mention "direct" or "indirect". Because something happens second that does not mean it is lesser than the thing that happens first, any more than the New Covenant is lesser than the Old, or Isaiah is lesser than Obadiah. Your presumption is directly contradicted by the Bible:

> So God created mankind in his own image,
> in the image of God he created them;
> male and female he created them. *Genesis 1:27*

Comment: What about Lot's Wife? (Luke 17:32) She became an inanimate object... but something tells me this wouldn't have happened if her gender differed (Jesus refers to her by her feminine title of "wife") What do you think?

Comment: I'm not going to discuss an entirely different question in comments. You've been on this site long enough to know that's not how it works.

Comment: @HolyKnowledge 'Something tells me' . . . . .  Can you be more specific about your source of knowledge, please ?

Comment: @NigelJ It comes from pattern matching. I saw that Jesus did not reveal her name but referred to her by a gendered title ("wife") so this must have been a significant detail in His eyes regarding her strange and alien fate.

Comment: Please don't use comments to discuss things not mentioned in either the question or the answer.